# Saving several Monticello packages at once

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I am working with Pharo Smalltalk. Suppose you want to save your own group of packages into a local repository, you know that your packages are prefixed with "MyPrefix". What's the right message to do it? In code:

```
| myPkgs |
myPkgs := MCPackage allInstances select: [: mcPkg | mcPkg name beginsWith: 'MyPrefix' ].
myPkgs do: [ : myPkg | myPkg ??? ].
```

It would be too difficult to script that one for a web based repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
packages := Gofer new allResolved
        collect: [ :each | each packageName ] as: Set.
packages := packages select: [ :e | e beginsWith: 'Prefix' ].

gofer := Gofer new
    disablePackageCache;
    directory: '/path/to/repo'.
packages do: [ :p | gofer package: p ].
gofer commit: ''.
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you load or update a group of packages:

```
Gofer new
    squeaksource: 'MyProject';
    package: 'MyPrefix-Core';
    package: 'MyPrefix-Tests';
    commit
```

More information you find in this blog post: [Gofer — Monticello and Groups of Packages](http://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/gofer).